# where clause on property of objects in a collection

Tags: hibernate, collections, hql

Simplified:

```
Class1 {
    private Collection<Class2> items;
}

Class2 {
    private String name;
}
```

Now I want to be able to retrieve all `Class1` objects that have a `Class2` object in `items` where `name` is `like` for example 'abc';

I think I have to use the `elements()` function in HQL, but not sure yet how to use the property values.

Any pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you just need to make a join:

```
select c1 from Class1 c1 inner join c1.items c2 where c2.name  = 'abc'
```

Read the Hibernate documentation on [HQL, associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

Comment: as i wrote in my (deleted answer) I think he can just do `where class1.items.name ...` if he is ok with an inner join...right?

Comment: No. You can only do that when traversing XxxtoOne associations.

Comment: I dont know why I didn't just try it like this, so simple. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, btw do you know if theres an alternative for Criteria API? I think I understand from what I've read this API does not support this (yet) ?

Comment: Of course it supports it: `criteria.createAlias("c1.items", "c2"); criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c2.name", "abc"));`. The same reference documentation also has a chapter on the Criteria API, which explains this as well.